# ApplicationBar appear after image_tap

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a page with listbox which inludes images.

```
            <ListBox Name="photoListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Photo}"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image  Source="{Binding xBig}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Tap="ImageTap" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

also, I have an ApplicationBar on my page, which is invisible while user dont tap image.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="AppBar" IsVisible="False">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="prevAppBarButton"
                                        IconUri="Images/appbar.transport.rew.rest.png"
                                        Text="previous"
                                        IsEnabled="False"
                                        />

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="playAppBarButton"
                                        IconUri="Images/appbar.transport.play.rest.png"
                                        Text="play"
                                         />

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="pauseAppBarButton"
                                        IconUri="Images/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png"
                                        Text="pause"
                                        IsEnabled="False"
                                         />

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="nextAppBarButton"
                                        IconUri="Images/appbar.transport.ff.rest.png"
                                        Text="next"
                                        IsEnabled="False"
                                        />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Image_Tap handler

```
    private void ImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        AppBar.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

But, then i tap to the image (i expect than my shell:ApplicationBar will appear) - i have a nullReferenceException. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the toolbar by using the [`ApplicationBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.applicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of your page:

```
private void ImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
}
```